# Why does my array double function not work?

Tags: c++

I tried making a function that **doubles an array passed into it, with only one for loop**, and adds the int 0 to each extra index that has no previous value.

I found that the last 3 elements end up being printed as a memory address.

Why does this not work and how can I fix it?

Example:

```
int array[] = { 3,5,6 };
int size = 3;
arrayDouble(array,size)
int array[] = { 3,5,6,0,0,0 }; //expected output
```

---

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int * arrayDouble(int array[], int size);

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 3,5,6 };
    int size = 3;
    int * ptrarray = arrayDouble(array, size);
}

int * arrayDouble(int array[], int size)
{
    int *new_array = new int[size * 2];

    for (int i = 1; i <= size * 2; i++)
    {
        if (i > (size * 2))
        {
            new_array[i - 1] = 0;
        }
        new_array[i - 1] = array[i - 1];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++)
    {

        cout << new_array[i];
    }

    return new_array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the issues with your loop.  However there is no need for two loops if you default initialize your entries when you use `new[]`.

Also, there is no need for even any loops if you use `std::copy` to copy the data from one array to the other.

Example:

```
int* arrayDouble(int array[], int size)
{
    int *new_array = new int[size * 2]();  // <-- Note the () to value-initialize the memory
    std::copy(array, array + size, new_array); // <-- Use copy to copy over the values to new_array

    // print results
    for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++)
        std::cout << new_array[i] << " ";

    return new_array;
}
```

[Live Example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f5100a5c6ef6c6f)

The `()` will automatically set the entries to the default value for `double`, which is 0.

With C++ 11, you can also use the brace initializer:

```
int *new_array = new int[size * 2]{};
```

---

But why do this when there is `std::vector` that does all of this work already, and without issues of potential memory leakage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array = { 3,5,6 };
    array.resize(array.size() * 2);
    for (auto v : array)
        std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

[Live Example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6f38ed8e7f69436)

Answer (score 0):

This section

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size * 2; i++)
{
    if (i > (size * 2)) // this never evaluates to true?
    {
        new_array[i - 1] = 0;
    }
    new_array[i - 1] = array[i - 1]; // this always happens

}
```

should really be

```
for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++)
{
    if (i > size)
    {
        new_array[i] = 0;
    }else{
        new_array[i] = array[i];
    }

}
```

Also, you will probably run into memory leaks if you don't manage all these arrays you're creating.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is wonky

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size * 2; i++)
{
    if (i > (size * 2))
    {
        new_array[i - 1] = 0;
    }
    new_array[i - 1] = array[i - 1];
}
```

should look like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++) //easier to understand if you just start with 0
{
    if (i > size) //you don't need to multiply by 2!!
    {
        new_array[i] = 0;
    }
    new_array[i] = array[i];
}
```

That should fix it for you

Answer (score -2):

I messed-up. I didn’t see I put size * 2